# Switch element types but keeping the same IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change the element type dynamically and below is how I am doing it:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.click_me').click(function(ev) {
    var condition_value_1 = $('#condition_value_1');
    var select_html = '<select name="condition_value_1" id="condition_value_1"></select>';
    condition_value_1.after().html(select_html);
    condition_value_1.remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="condition_value_1">
<span class="click_me">Click Me</span>
```

After change the types as you see on the snippet above I should remove the previous element but because they share (and this is mandatory) the same ID then the new SELECT gets deleted. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: `they share (and this is mandatory) the same ID` Why is it mandatory? It's invalid HTML and causes issues with JS (as you've discovered) when you have repeated `id` attributes. You should replace each `input`/`select` as you toggle them instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no, it will no causes issues because the idea is turn on the INPUT into a SELECT and it's mandatory because if I change the value I might be involve on change to much code on backend side to make this work again

Comment: use the name attribute instead of the id to delete

Comment: @KevinKloet good point, this would work, if you like add an answer with a little example and I will accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to replace, you can use replaceWith..

```js
$(function() {
  $('.click_me').click(function(ev) {
    var condition_value_1 = $('#condition_value_1');
    var select_html = '<select name="condition_value_1" id="condition_value_1"></select>';
    condition_value_1.replaceWith(select_html);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="condition_value_1">
<span class="click_me">Click Me</span>
```

Comment: Yes you deserve it

Answer (score 1):

use the name attribute instead of the id to delete

```
$(function() {
  $('.click_me').click(function(ev) {
    var condition_value_1 = $('#condition_value_1');
    var select_html = '<select name="condition_value_1" id="condition_value_1"></select>';
    condition_value_1.after().html(select_html);
    $('[name="ElementNameHere"]')[0].remove();
  });
});
```

note that this will only delete the first entry it gets into when searching the DOM.